# Remove and Understand two Particular Substrings from a RegEx in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like the following:

```
s: str = 'ENGBNAmphitheatre Pkwy\x1e\x1eNASY%am|fi|te|"a|tre;ENGY*"{m|fI|%Ti|t@r;ENGY"{m|fI|%Ti|t@r *"pArk|%we;NASY%am|fi|te|"a|tre "par|kwei'
```

I want to extract a string between two substring patterns using compound Regex (without using two separate replace commands).

Below is an explanation of which strings I'd like to replace with blanks, thus leaving the middle section which is what I want to extract.

```
# Replace leading 'ENGBN' with '' (blank)
pat1: str = "ENGBN"

# Replace this specific substring (that has special characters such as \x1e) with '' (blank)
pat2: str = """\x1e\x1eNASY%am|fi|te|"a|tre;ENGY*"{m|fI|%Ti|t@r;ENGY"{m|fI|%Ti|t@r *"pArk|%we;NASY%am|fi|te|"a|tre "par|kwei"""
```

Desired Result:

```
result: str = "Amphitheatre Pkwy"
```

I'm trying to learn more about Regex in general, so an explanation of what the proposed single pattern is doing is also desired.

Comment: `x = re.compile('ENGBN.*\x1e\x1e<rest of the string>')`. Now you can test candidates with `m = x.fullmatch(candidate)` ... If the value is truthy, extract the matched string `m.group(0)`, and "peel" its head ("ENGBN") and its tail ('\x1e\x1e<rest of the string>') ... and Bob's your uncle !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call `re.sub` specifying as the search string the two individual strings you want to replace combined with the `|` operator. Because the second search string contains special characters recognized as regex operators, e.g. '|', this string needs to be properly escaped:

```py
import re

s = 'ENGBNAmphitheatre Pkwy\x1e\x1eNASY%am|fi|te|"a|tre;ENGY*"{m|fI|%Ti|t@r;ENGY"{m|fI|%Ti|t@r *"pArk|%we;NASY%am|fi|te|"a|tre "par|kwei'
search_string_1 = "^ENGBN" # ENGBN at the start of the string
search_string_2 = re.escape('\x1e\x1eNASY%am|fi|te|"a|tre;ENGY*"{m|fI|%Ti|t@r;ENGY"{m|fI|%Ti|t@r *"pArk|%we;NASY%am|fi|te|"a|tre "par|kwei')
# Or just use the following based on the OP's comment below:
#search_string_2 = r'\x1e[\s\S]*$'
print(re.sub(f'{search_string_1}|{search_string_2}', '', s))
```

Prints:

```None
Amphitheatre Pkwy
```

**Update**

To search for a string between two substrings (assuming the first substring is of constant length, otherwise use the `regex` package from the PyPi repository):

```py
import re

s = 'ENGBNAmphitheatre Pkwy\x1e\x1eNASY%am|fi|te|"a|tre;ENGY*"{m|fI|%Ti|t@r;ENGY"{m|fI|%Ti|t@r *"pArk|%we;NASY%am|fi|te|"a|tre "par|kwei'
search_string_1 = "^ENGBN"
search_string_2 = '\x1e'
print(re.search(f'(?<={search_string_1}).*?(?={search_string_2})', s).group(0))
```

Prints:

```None
Amphitheatre Pkwy
```

Comment: This is great and makes sense. Is there a way to remove just everything from '\x1e' to end of string?. Lets say I just want what is between ENGBN and the first \x1e?

Comment: Actually think I answered my own question with ```re.search(r'^ENGBN(.*?)\x1e').group(1)```

Comment: I have updated my answer to address your first comment. But your second comment suggests that you do not want to do any replacements at all whereas your question explicitly specifies two separate  string replacements and I made no assumption as to what strings you wanted to replace. You should really update your question to make it clearer.

Comment: sorry. its semantics. My end result is the same either way. To replace something with ```''``` and to find something in between two strings (and thus innately removing those outside strings) accomplishes the same end goal here. I apologise for not properly wording my question.

Comment: But it's far simpler to just search for something between two strings.  If the first search string is of fixed length, then I would probably use a lookbehind assertion and a lookahead assertion, which actually does not match anything but asserts respectively that the current position is preceded or followed by a certain substring. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one `pattern = r'(?<=^ENGBN)[^\x1e]+'`

It will extract substring that is preceded by "ENGBN" and consists of one or more characters that are not `\x1e`.

Here is a link with a complete solution [trinket.io/python/082a3601c1](https://trinket.io/python/082a3601c1)

Comment: How do you get "Amphitheatre Pkwy" as the result after replacement?

Comment: Yes! I tried it and I replaced the match with '' and got 'ENGBN\x1e\x1eNASY%am|fi|te|"a|tre;ENGY*"{m|fI|%Ti|t@r;ENGY"{m|fI|%Ti|t@r *"pArk|%we;NASY%am|fi|te|"a|tre "par|kwei'.

Comment: Did you try it?

Here is a link with a complete solution https://trinket.io/python/082a3601c1

Comment: The OP wants to replace two substrings in the input string with ''. In this case the resulting string just happens to be adjacent characters, which your regex is trying to match. But you are doing a match based on the assumption that  the answer is substring of the original string. But you cannot assume that and you must do 2 replacements.

Comment: why I cannot assume that?
OP wrote under your solution: "I just want what is between ENGBN and the first \x1e" and this is what exactly you can achieve with my solution.

Comment: The OP just posted a comment to my answer suggesting that what you are doing is okay. But having already downvoted this, I cannot undo the downvote unless you modify your answer. So just make a trivial edit (e.g. put a '^' character before 'ENGBN' since the OP said it is at the beginning of the line ) and let me know when done.

Comment: I have removed the downvote and added an upvote.